# Cuando se puede usar not in

Tags: python, string

Se pude usar el not in en un string ? o solo se utiliza con las listas? Por ejemplo de esta forma?

```
 if listaPalabras[0] not in vocalMayusc:

        nueva.append(palab)

print(nueva)
```

Comment: Se puede usar con cualquier "colección". Eso incluye listas, tuplas, diccionarios, cadenas y conjuntos. Pero cuidado porque del ejemplo que pones deduzco que no haría lo que quizás pretendes. Lo que hará será mirar si `listaPalabras[0]` (que supongo es una cadena), no forma parte de la cadena `vocalMayus`. Por ejemplo, si la palabra es "HOLA" y `vocalMayus` es "AEIOU", el `if` sería cierto, ya que la secuencia "HOLA" no forma parte de la secuencia "AEIOU".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El operador de membresía `in` (y, por lo tanto, la negación del mismo, i.e: `not in`) se puede usar en cualquier objeto que haya realizado una implementación del *magic method* `__contains__`.

> Vale notar que: Si el método `__contains__` no está implementado, Python intentará iterar sobre el objeto, en caso de que este sea iterable (si define o `__iter__` o `__getitem`__), y descubrir si la membresía existe. Más información en [la documentación oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations)

En consecuencia, podemos comprobar que los iterables básicos que existen en Python contemplan una implementación de este método. Es decir, podemos hacer uso del operador `in` con objetos de esos tipos.

```py
>>> dir(list)
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', # ...
>>> dir(tuple)
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', # ...
>>> dir(str)
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', # ...
>>> dir(set)
['__and__', '__class__', '__contains__', # ...
>>> dir(dict)
['__class__', '__contains__', # ...
>>> dir(range)
['__bool__', '__class__', '__contains__', # ...
```

Como te podrás imaginar, también podemos crear nuestros propios tipos de datos que implementen el método `__contains__` para que podamos usar el operador `in` y así consigamos un código muy legible en muchas ocasiones. Ojo, que **no** es necesario que nuestros *custom objects* sean iterables para hacer esto posible.

Mira este ejemplo de un código en el que trabajé hace un tiempo y que lucía (más o menos) así:

```py
class Inventory:
    def __init__(self, repository):
        self.repository = repository

    def __contains__(self, product):
        try:
            retrieved_product = self.get_product(whose='id', equals=product.id)
            return retrieved_product is not None
        except LookupError:
            return False

    def get_product(self, whose, equals):
        record = self.repository.get(whose, equals)
        return Product(*record)

    # ... other methods (like add() )
```

Con esa implementación puedo hacer uso de sentencias como:

```
>>> inventory.add(product)
>>> product in inventory      # <---------- Acá
True
```

Comment: Buena respuesta. Como bonus podrías comentar que también `range()` implementa `__contains__`, cosa que me sorprendió cuando lo descubrí y que te permite hacer algo como `if x in range(10, 20)`

Comment: Gracias, @abulafia. Te juro por Dios y mi madre que creí que había incluido `range()`. Incluso, en mi sesión REPL que copié y pegué, lo tenía plasmado! Pero bueno, gracias por notarlo. Ya lo incluyo.

Answer (score 2):

Pudiste comprobarlo tu mismo, pero si, se puede:

```
>>> a = "abcd"
>>> "b" not in a
False
>>> "f" not in a
True
>>> "bc" not in a
False
```

La razón: en Python, los strings son iterables y puedes hacer algunas operaciones con ellos como si fueran listas.